# Sphinx filtering with dropdown lists

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I have just finished implementing a full-text search engine powered by sphinx using PHP and MySQL. However I would like to add filtering using drop down lists.
I would be more grateful if someone could assist me on that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for attributes
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#attributes

but really not a lot more can be said, without more detail. Ask a specific question get a specific answer. Ask a general question get a general answer.

Comment: My search engine performs a search after inputting a word or a phrase. And I have a dropdown menu to select the type of the document (which is an attribute in the database) we want to perform the search in (more like filtering).

Comment: How to retrieve the value from the dropdown list to perform the filtering.

Comment: With code! Depends on exactly how you've structed the site, if would be best implemented in php, or client side, possibly using ajax and javascript. Probably easier to get the list from mysql, rather than sphinx. But it depends.